# Restore original image from multiple watermarked

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, interpolation

I have multiple images with some watermark. Every watermark the same shape, consists of white (#fff) and black (#000) colors, but with random proportions:

- opacity 10-15%
- height 95-100%
- y position: from middle +- ~20px
- slight deformations

For a start I detect [the lightest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24s1j.jpg) and [the darkest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNifB.jpg) variants.
Also, I can take a list of positions differing pixels. So, how can I restore [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGmiS.jpg)?

I have many ideas, but each of them ends in failure in certain situations. Is it possible to solve this problem without using neural networks and additional libraries (like OpenCV)?

Thanks for any help, I've been puzzling for over a week.

Comment: Why do you not want to use OpenCV or NNs? This is not an easy problem, you could try solving them with just OpenCV, maybe, depending on the scope of the problem. That itself would be very difficult, I imagine. I don't think there is a way to solve this easily. The best shot would be to use a NN approach.

Comment: could you supply a handful or more variants of one picture, for demo purposes?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, It can be any image on top of which there is a watermark consisting only of white and black, but with a different position and transparency for each image. This way we get a map of different pixels. The task is to determine for each pixel its original color

Comment: I've posted an answer. does that help you?

Comment: Already solved here on SO: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461350/remove-text-from-jpeg/52523303#52523303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52461350/remove-text-from-jpeg/52523303#52523303)

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the same image but some pixels are disturbed in each version...

stack them, take the **median**.

mathematically you'd want the "mode" but median is a more common operation. either will yield the majority value for every pixel (or something close enough), which should be the untouched value for that pixel.

you can do that with just numpy for the median, and scikit-image to load the files.

if you have pixels that are always covered with the watermark in all versions, the situation becomes tricky. you'd have to formulate some model of the watermark's effect on the pixels. I think that's doable but quite some work.